# Stuck on JS course (Codecademy) Search Text for Your Name 5/7

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with a section on the Codecademy JavaScript course. I have read the instructions multiple times, and I've even looked up other answers. I'm stuck.

Here is my Javascript

```
var text = "My name is Greyson because my parents named me Greyson.";
var myName = "Greyson";
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++);
{
  if(text[i] === "G")
  {
    for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)
    {
        hits.push(text[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

When I click submit, it gives me the following error:

"**Oops, try again. It looks like your second 'for' loop isn't pushing values to the hits array. Make sure it's working properly and that myName's text appears somewhere in the text variable.**"

I've looked up other peoples answers to compare the two, and it seems like mine is pretty much identical to some of the answers I've been receiving.

Comment: Can you add some more context such as: is your code required to return `hits`? What is the exact format of the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for not giving any more explanation. It turns out I was just blocking my first `for` variable with a `;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of the top line of your `for` loop

The line should read - `for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)`, not `for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++);`

Comment: Unbelievable... Hahahaha! Thanks a ton man. I scanned it so many times and I just missed a semicolon. I'm probably just too sleep deprived to be learning right now. xD

Comment: Just one thing - this will return 'Greyson' in 'Greysons', too... Do you need exact match?